# Typo3 realurl wrong defaultValue in links after clearCache

Tags: typo3, realurl

I´m running a Typo3 4.5.12 and the realurl extension verson 1.11.1.
My site has 3 languages de, en, ch and the default language is de, german.

If I clear the cache of realurl and call first www.example.com/site all is ok.

But if I call after clearCache first for example a url with language-param like www.example.com/en/site and after that www.example.com/site, all links get the ../en/.. in the href-tag like www.example.com/en/site2.

It´s the same when I call first after clearCache a site with ../ch/.. or ../de/..

Why he don´t pick the default-language when I call www.example.com/site in links?

My config of realurl:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(
    init' => array(
        'enableCHashCache' => 1,
        'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
        'enableUrlDecodeCache' => 1,
        'enableUrlEncodeCache' => 1,
        'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
    ),
    'redirects_regex' => array (
    ),
    'preVars' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
            'valueMap' => array('no_cache' => 1),
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'L',
            'valueMap' => array(
                'de' => '0',
                'en' => '1',
                'cn' => '2',
            ),
            'defaultValue' => 'de',
            'noMatch' => 'bypass',
        ),
    ),
...
```

My page config:

```
simulateStaticDocuments = 0
tx_realurl_enable = 1
prefixLocalAnchors = all

linkVars = mobile(off),L
uniqueLinkVars = 1

sys_language_uid = 0
language = de
locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8

sys_language_mode = content_fallback
sys_language_overlay = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[...]
'defaultValue' => 'de',
'noMatch' => 'bypass',
[...]
```

Are somewhat contra dictionary.

Take the `noMatch` out, this will create url's like:

```
/site1 (german)
/en/site1 (english)
/cn/site1 (chinese)
```

Otherwise go for

```
'noMatch' => 'de' //(without `'defaultValue' => 'de'`)
```

to get

```
/de/site1 (german)
/en/site1 (english)
/cn/site1 (chinese)
```

Comment: Hi @konsolenfreddy - I am having a similar / identical issue with current realURL, but your solution 'nomatch' => 'de' wouldn't work. Do you still recommend that to get /de/site1, /en/site1 etc?

Comment: there seems to be something mixed up here, the first setup creates the result for the secont example, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109737/realurl-not-writing-prevar-for-default-language/